# Return messes up methods array.map and array.filter

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

In my PWA I have two caches:

[image]

So I did a bit of test in the console to see if I can delete one:

[image]

And it worked:

[image]

But in my web worker I have this activate event handler. Which **(a)** checks through multiple caches using `caches.keys()`, **(b)** filters out the caches that have a different name than the cache that I set as `const c = "my_cache"` and **(c)** deletes those caches.

```
const c = "my_cache";

// Listen for the activate event.
self.addEventListener("activate",
    (e) => {
        e.waitUntil(
            caches.keys().then(
                (k) => {
                    return Promise.all(
                        k.filter(
                            kk => kk !== c
                        ).map(
                            kk => caches.delete(kk)
                        )
                    );
                }
            )
        );
    }
);
```

I read in the official documentation ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) that in arrow functions `return` can be omitted if you only have one statement, because this statement is return statement. Right?

But then why this stops to work if I rewrite the arrow functions like this:

```
const c = "my_cache";

// Listen for the activate event.
self.addEventListener("activate",
    (e) => {
        e.waitUntil(
            caches.keys().then(
                (k) => {
                    return Promise.all(
                        k.filter(
                            (kk) => {
                                return (kk !== c);
                            }
                        ).map(
                            (kk) => {
                                return caches.delete(kk);
                            }
                        )
                    );
                }
            )
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: `k.filter((kk) => {kk !== c;}` doesn't do anything at all. You'd filter everything out. If you claim that it "works", then I'd say that it does so because having anything in your array is a problem. Can you prepare a [mcve]? Because currently you have a lot of code, so it's not easy to see what's expected to happen or why it happens.

Comment: If you have curly braces (a function body) you must use return; the first code (“working” code) isn’t doing what you think it is.

Comment: does caches.keys() return a promise? also, promise.all is probably not doing what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Neither “filter” and “map” return a “modified array”, as it states they return a *new* array, filter by filtering based on the return value of the method passed in, map by collecting the return value of the function you pass in.

Comment: @DaveNewton Than what does my so called "working example" actualy do?

Comment: @71GA See VLAZ’s comment.

Comment: @Dave Newton I updated my question. Was @VLAZ trying to say that I should use `k.filter((kk) => kk !== c` instead of `k.filter((kk) => {kk !== c;}`. Because if there are curly braces I can't ommit `return`... ?

Comment: VLAZ was saying that your filter was non-functional. I was saying it's because you don't have a return; if you have a function body (i.e., inside `{}`) must have a return. Implicit returns only work if it's a single statement.

Comment: Okay that is what I thought. I was tweaking my code a bit and worked this one out. Thank you all.